# Checked out a different branch. Why is HEAD still pointing to master branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I checked out someone else's branch and tracking it.

```
git checkout --track origin/foo
```

However, even though I checked out a different branch (not the `master` branch), why is `HEAD` still pointing to `master`?

When I type `git branch -a`, I get this. So I can't do things like `git reset HEAD^ --hard`

```
  master  
* foo  
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master  
  remotes/origin/foo
```

I basically want to check out someone else's branch, and work on it.
Also, commit and push into his branch.

Comment: Will I be able to commit to this branch ? even if this branch is generated by another user ? I saw some post like you need to put `-u` option to `git push` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HEAD` isn't pointing to `master`. This output:

```
* foo
```

means that your local `HEAD` is pointing to `foo`. The asterisk (`*`) represents `HEAD`.

You may have been confused by this line:

```
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

which means that the *remote* `HEAD` is pointing to the remote `master`. This has no effect on your local `HEAD`.

As [@eddiem mentioned](//stackoverflow.com/a/40246399/2747593), in the future, to check out a local branch that tracks `origin/foo`, just do:

```
git checkout foo
```

(This assumes you don't already have a local branch called `foo`.)

Comment: "remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master" yes, i was confused by this line... Thanks for the comment !

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to `git checkout foo`, and it will automatically know to track the correct upstream branch.